# cloning div according to number selected in jquery

Tags: jquery, select, clone

I need some serious help! I am trying to create a hotel search engine. I need to get the number of rooms from a select box and clone a div of select boxes the same number of times as selected in the rooms select box. I hope this makes sense. I also need to change the text of the div to Room 1, Room 2, Room 3 etc. Here is a jsfiddle of what I have started and I do not know where to go from here.
http://jsfiddle.net/liveandream/YxXtY/
and here is my code:
HTML:

```
Rooms:<select name="rooms" id='rooms'>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select><br>
<div id="room">Room 1:
<br />
<div class='left' >Adults:
    <select name="adults" id='adults'>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option></select></div>
 <div class='left'>Children:
   <select name="children" id="children">
        <option selected="selected">0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select></div>
<div class='left' id="childage">Child Ages:
    <select name="children" >
        <option selected="selected">0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select></div><br clear="all" /></div>
<div id="txt"></div>
```

​JQUERY:

```
$("select#rooms").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select#rooms option:selected").each(function () {
                $("#room").clone(2).insertAfter("#txt");
              });
          $("#txt").text(str);
        })
        .change();​
```

Thank you in advance to anyone willing to help!

EDIT: I need it to be something like this: http://www.helloweekends.com/

Comment: If you properly indent your code more people will be able to help...

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ryanfernandes/YxXtY/81/ See if its what you're looking for.

I touched-up the html so that your divs have unique ids and included functionality to remove/hide the rooms based on the number selected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just copying the element from existing HTML, it'd be better to create those elements with JavaScript. So for your function that's called when the selected number of rooms is changed, something like

```
 function () {
    var html = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < this.value; i++)
    {
       html += "<div class='room'>Room " + (i + 1);
       html += "<br clear='all' />";   
       html += "<div class='left' >Adults:<select name='adults' id='adults'>";        

       // ... Create the rest of the form part for the room  ...

    }    
    $("#roomsContainer").html(html); // #roomsContainer is a container around where the
                                     // menus for the individual rooms should be. 
}
```